# Loading popover with Jquery mobile when linking an external website.

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

Im trying to load an external website using jquery mobile and have a loading png so that only once the external websites page has loaded the loading png disappears.

Any idea how to create this effect with jquery mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind functions to the ajax start, stop and error events to show your png

```
// error with request
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, xhr, settings, error){
 // something went wrong
});

// show loading indicator
// when ajax requests start
$(document).ajaxStart(function (){
 showLoadingGraphic();
});

// remove loading indicator
// when ajax requests complete
$(document).ajaxStop(function (){
 hideLoadingGraphic();
});
```